# Apply DB2 logs from production to DR

Tags: db2, db2-9.5

Is it possible to Apply DB2 9.5 logs files from Production site to DR site? Or do I have to do Backup/Restore and rollforward ...?

I copied log files from production site to DR and issued the following command:

`rollforward db DBNAME to end of logs and stop overflow log path (/home/db2inst1/logs) noretrieve`

Got the error:

> DB is not in Rollforward Pending

Comment: If you send the logs to the DR site and you "open" the database (stop roll forwarding), check your DB2 license, because in this case you will need another one. You cannot have two active databases in two different machines with just one license.

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-1311db2halicensing/index.html?ca=drs

Answer (score 1):

As the error says, the database must be in the `Rollforward pending` state for you to use the `rollforward` command. However, while in this state the database is not accessible.

You don't explain what it is that you are trying to achieve so it's hard to provide a precise solution. If this is a one-time activity you will need to restore your DR database from a backup and run `rollforward`. If your intent is to keep the DR database up to date on an ongoing basis, consider [setting up HADR](https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.ha.doc/doc/t0011725.html), which automates the process of transferring and applying logged changes to the standby database.

Comment: I wanted a temporary way to keep our DR machine synced with PR machine until setting up HADR :) So I thought maybe I can rollforward DB2 and apply logs manually...

Comment: In that case you have to keep your pseudo-DR database in the `rollforward pending` mode. Issue the `rollforward` command without specifying the `complete` (or `stop`) keyword.